# Disabling Hat EEPROM scan

Tags: i2c, hat

How do I free the Hat EEPROM  I2C bus (bus 0?) on a + model? I ask because the primary bus is blocked by an TFT I'm using, and I want to solder nothing to the Pi GPIO.

Answer (score 2):

I am a silly person who can't google!

ShiftPlusOne says...

> ...but you should be able to just add bcm2708.vc_i2c_override=1 to cmdline.txt and use it like you normally would.

[B+ disable ID_EEPROM](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=89586)